# rails has_many: through not working when using the word "connection"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm able to successfully create a through table using the naming convention of `friends` and `friend`. However I'd like to use `connections` instead of `friends`.

Active record throws the following error when I try to use `connections`: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column medical_relationships.connection_id does not exist`

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many: :medical_relationships
  has_many: :friends, through: :medical_relationships
  # I'd like to use 
  # has_many: :connections, through: :medical_relationships

class MedicalRelationship < AR::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
  # belongs_to :connection, :class_name => "User"
```

this seems to be a singular and plural naming convention issue in rails but I'm not sure.

Comment: you will need the class name in both directions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That id does not exist on the medical_relationships table. You can either add `:foreign_key => :user_id` (assuming that is your user table's primary key) or change the name of the column in the table. I would advise against the second.

Comment: ah gotcha. I was completely off conceptually. It's because I have a column in the db `friend_id` that the above works. If I changed that to `connection_id` it would work with `connections`?